# Rails - Map Function Alternative to Return Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this line in the index action of my controller:

```
@orders = Order.all.map{|k| k.transaction}.keep_if{ |a| a != nil }
```

The problem is, `@orders` is returning an array. I need @orders to be Object like `Order.all` to use it properly with `will_paginate` and `pundit` GEMS.

Is there any object returning alternative of `map` method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `transaction`? Is that a db field or association? Or is it a ruby method?

Comment: @ouranos a model. Order has_one transaction.

Comment: ok, @fivedigit was quicker :)

Comment: So do you want transactions or orders to be returned? Your code right now returns transactions, but the variable name suggests you'd want to have orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `transaction` is an association in your `Order` model, you could simply run a query selecting only orders with a transaction:

```
Order.where.not(transaction_id: nil)
```

You could take this one step further and defining this as a scope in `Order`:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :transaction

  scope :with_transaction, -> { where.not(transaction_id: nil) }
end
```

Then, in your controller you can simply do this, and not be bothered with the details of your model's internals:

```
Order.with_transaction
```

You can read more about [ActiveRecord scopes in the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Comment: Actually, that'd be slightly different as the OP method returns the transactions. So I'd suggest `Order.with_transaction.include(:transaction).map(&:transaction)`

Comment: Ah I misread, he wants it to return the same objets as `Order.all` so your suggestion is right!

Comment: You're right. It's bit unclear though, I asked for details ;) Otherwise, the solution would simply be `Transaction.all` or alike.